# Multiple bool clauses in elasticsearch filter/query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How should I translate this SQL query into an elasticsearch query?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (id = 99 AND isonline <> 1) OR (id = 98 AND isonline <> 0)
```

How do I make a query that has multiple bool filters? (bonus would be to also show how to do it in NEST)

The elastic query I've come up with doesn't work because it contains duplicate object keys.

```
{
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "id": 99
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "isonline": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "id": 98
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "isonline": false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }        
    }
}
```

*elasticsearch version 1.7*

Comment: Is it me or your `WHERE` statement doesn't make sense? `(id = 99 AND isonline <> 1) AND (id = 98 AND isonline <> 0)` id is both 99 and 98...

Comment: @AndreiStefan I'm sorry you are right. I've edited the query from using 'AND' to using 'OR' which was what I meant to do. Basically I want to match against the ID and the isonline status. I will have these conditions for each item I want to find.

Comment: Hehe, makes sense now. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "id": 99
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "isonline": false
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "id": 98
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "isonline": true
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The query returns 0 hits. If I remove one of the inner bool conditions then I get back at least 1 result though. But with more than 1 bool condition inside the must it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you answer my question from your post?  
Is it me or your WHERE statement doesn't make sense? `(id = 99 AND isonline <> 1) AND (id = 98 AND isonline <> 0)` id is both 99 and 98... what actually are you looking for?