# How to reference particular fields in the individual indices when searching through alias in elasticsearch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, querydsl

```
const elasticsearch = new Client({ node: `http://localhost:9200` })

const response = await elasticsearch.search({
  index: companyIndex,
  body: {
    query:{
      query_string: {
        query: queryText,
        fields: ['name', 'insuredName', 'instigator']
      }
   }
  }
});
```

Here `companyIndex` is the alias of the three indices company-events, company-insureds, company-files.
This search will only search through the most primary fields across three indices. There fields include:

company index:

- insuredName
- instigator

company insureds index:

- name

company files index:

- name

In the above code, I just made query fields for the three indices. I want to split across three indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one way of doing this if you have `_index` field in your document.

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "should": [{
        "terms":{
          "_index":["company_insureds"]
        }},
        {
         "term":{
          "name":"nameValue"
        }
      }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To achieve the things with other fields, you can refer [multi-bool clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013655/multiple-bool-clauses-in-elasticsearch-filter-query)

If you don't have `_index` in you index, there is no way of doing this.